# Tinkerpop/Gremlin: How to join multiple traversals and use their value in a main traversal?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I want to use the result of two traversals `a, b` to calculate the value for an property. I don't know how to join them into `combinedTraversal` with both traversals starting from the origin element/vertex.

```
        Graph graph = TinkerFactory.createModern();

        GraphTraversal a = __.values("age").count().as("count")
                .constant(10).as("allCount")
                .math("count / allCount")
//              .as("a");

        GraphTraversal b = __.values("age").count().as("count")
                .constant(10).as("allCount")
                .math("count / allCount")
//              .as("b");

        GraphTraversal combinedTraversal = __ 
                .local(a).as("a")
                .local(b).as("b")
                .math("a * b");

        graph.traversal().V()
                .has("age")
                .property(Cardinality.single, "value", combinedTraversal)
                .iterate();
```

In the example, traversal a and b assume to start at a given vertex and calculate their value. When i'm using `local()` the position of the traversal is changed and I don't know how to step back to the origin.

Using `sideEffect()` on the other hand does not refer to the current element, instead calculating the values for all elements into a map.

Is there any way to build such a `combinedTraversal`? (The "complex" calculation traversals are chosen on purpose, of course there are simpler ways to solve this example)

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: **projection** https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#project-step

```
GraphTraversal combinedTraversal = __.project("a", "b").by(a).by(b).math("a * b");
```